# What is the name of HEVC input frame?

Tags: hevc

I am working on rate control algorithms in HEVC. I have a problem. Can any one help me with how can I find each frame of an input video in HEVC? (Because I need to work on each frame as a distinct image but I don't know in what variable in HEVC each input frame is stored an processed.)

Answer (score 0):

To find new frame

1. Parse the input data as per HEVC draft (annex B) to find start of frame (start_code_prefix_one_3bytes ). This will give you new NAL units.
2. If you find VCL-NAL parse slice header and find value of **first_slice_segment_in_pic_flag** equal to 1 specifies that the slice segment is the first slice segment of the picture in decoding order.
3. Do same process until you will get next vcl nal containing **first_slice_segment_in_pic_flag** equal to 1. So this will indicate you this is the start of new or next frame.